# Replacing A with An if next word starts with a vowel

Tags: javascript, string

I hacked up a simple solution, but it looks a little dirty to me so I was hoping somebody would be able to show me a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Essentially I'm just trying to make the returned string valid English by converting A to An if the next word begins with a vowel.

ie:

> A ball is round
>   An elephant is grey

The way that I've done it is to just make a function that I call whenever I'm using the value of A and return A or An.

```
function convertAorAn(val){
    const letter = val.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    if(
        letter === 'a' ||
        letter === 'e' ||
        letter === 'i' ||
        letter === 'o' ||
        letter === 'u'
     ) {
        return "An"
    } else {
        return "A"
    }
}
```

And use it as such:

`{convertAorAn(value)} {value} is {otherValue}`

To achieve:
**A laptop is thin**
or
**An alligator is rough**

Is there a better way to do this conversion than my function written?

Comment: You could put all your vowels in a `Set` and then test whether that set `.has` your `letter`

Comment: There is not really that much point to your exercise as the "a"/"an" thing does not depend on spelling but on pronunciation like in "a European country" and "an LSD trip".

Comment: @cars10m Of course you're correct, but I'm attempting to cover the majority of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. There are other possible solutions, of course. One would be to replace your `if` with a `switch`:

```
function convertAorAn(val){
  switch (val.charAt(0).toLowerCase()) {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
      return 'An';
    default:
      return 'A';
  }
}
```

Another would be to use `includes` instead of checking for each letter individually:

```
function convertAorAn(val){
  const letter = val.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  if ('aeiou'.includes(letter)) {
    return 'An';
  }
  return 'A';
}
```

Finally, you could use a regular expression to match the first character in `val`:

```
function convertAorAn(val){
  return /^[aeiou]/i.test(val) ? 'An' : 'A';
}
```

In the end it's really a matter of style and what will be most readable to you and your team six months down the road.

Comment: I believe the reg ex solution is the best in this context :)

Answer (score 1):

I didnt see this one but it was mentioned.

```
function convertAorAn(val){
  s = new Set(['a','e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])
  const letter = val.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  return s.has(letter) ? 'An' : 'A';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convertAorAn(val){
  return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].some(currentVal => currentVal === val) ? 'An' : 'A';
}

let result1 = convertAorAn('a');
console.log(result1); // output => An
let result2 = convertAorAn('b');
console.log(result2); // output => A
```

You can use Array.some to achieve the required result

Reference: [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the vowel check with includes

```
function convertAorAn(val){
  const letter = val.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  const isVowel = 'aeiou'.includes(letter);
  return isVowel ? "An" : "A";
}
```

I would do it all with a regex with replace to match `a` and `an` and replace them with capitalization. Cleaned up the vowel check with a sting includes.

```js
function cleanA (str) {
  const vowels = 'aeiou'
  return str.replace(/\b(an?)\s(.)/gi, function (m, a, l) {
    const word = (a[0] === 'A' ? 'A' : 'a') + (vowels.includes(l.toLowerCase()) ? 'n' : '');
    return `${word} ${l}`
  })
}


console.log(cleanA('A ball is round. A apple is red. I love an red firetruck with a ladder.'))
```